# String does not convert to integer in Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

Sorry if this already being asked before, but I can't find any solution that match my problem.

I'm trying to convert the string that I have to convert to an integer:

```yaml
- hosts: myhost
  vars:
    - variable1: 15
    - variable2: "15"
    - variable3: "{{ variable2 | int }}"
```

I tried to use `variable2` (string) for calculation, so I convert it to int in `variable3`. But it failed with error message

> "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ variable3 + 1 }}): coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found"

So, I tried to use `type_debug` to find out each type of the 3 variable listed.

- `variable1` is `int`
- `variable2` is `ansibleunicode`
- `variable3` is `unicode`

I don't understand the difference between `ansibleunicode` and `unicode` or why it is listed as unicode instead of integer when I already convert it from string to integer using `| int`.
What should I do?

Comment: There's a relevant Github issue related to the problem you are facing: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/30366: "Unfortunately due to how jinja2 works, it technically only has the ability to return strings. Any time you use jinja2 templating, the result comes out as a string. So while |int is internally converting the value to an int, the final result from jinja2 is a string. We have some type guessing capabilities, but that typically only works when there is no jinja2 pipeline in the templating, instead when it is just an individual variable."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following.

```
- hosts: myhost
  vars:
    - variable1: 15
    - variable2: "15"

  tasks:
  - name: test 
    debug: msg="{{ variable2 | int + 1}}"
    delegate_to: localhost
```

**output:**

```
TASK [test] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [remote -> localhost] => {
    "msg": "16"
}
```

Comment: I accept you answer as it works, but i still don't understand why variable3 type is unicode instead of integer when i already convert it

Answer (score 5):

Q: *"**I still don't understand why variable3 type is Unicode instead of an integer when I already convert it.**"*

A: The output of [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#) is always  *string*. It's a template designer. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} is {{ item|type_debug }}"
      loop:
        - "{{ var1 }}"
        - "{{ var2 }}"
        - "{{ var1|int }}"
        - "{{ var2|int }}"
      vars:
        var1: 15
        var2: "15"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 15 is int
  msg: 15 is str
  msg: 15 is str
  msg: 15 is str
```

Only the first item is recognized as *integer*. There is no expression in the first item, hence Ansible doesn't call Jinja to evaluate it. Instead, Ansible takes the value of the variable directly. If an expression is evaluated by Jinja the type of the output is always *string*.