# How to render a literal 'null' in Jinja2 Template

Tags: ansible, null, jinja2, default, literals

I'm working on an ansible role that allow users to interact with a REST API. I create json.j2 templates that allow me to build the message payload and eventually submit. One of the fields expects either a string value (`""`) or `null`.

```json
{
  "value": "{{ example.value | default(null, true) }}"
}
```

This doesn't work and I get this error:

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'null' is undefined

I need that null value and I need to come in as the default value if no other value is provided.
How do I do this?

Comment: Ansible is Python based. The null value in Python is `None` => `default(None, true)`

Comment: @Zeitounator None does not equal null. None in this place will lead to...
`
{
    value: ""
}
`
When what I want is...
`
{
    value: null
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71927568/how-to-render-a-literal-null-in-jinja2-template#comment127099664_71927568), `null` has no meaning in Python, `None` is the Python representation of what your are looking for.

Now, if you want to convert this to a JSON value, then there is a [`to_json`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filter-to-json-and-unicode-support) filter in Ansible, so:

```yaml
'{ "value": {{ example.value | default(None, true) | to_json }} }'
```

Would end up as:

```json
{ "value": null }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `None | to_json` always renders as `"null"`, not `null`

Comment: @bmaupin in which context are you testing this? Mind that a debug task always yields a string: `- debug: msg="{{ None | to_json }}"` >  `ok: [localhost] => { "msg": "null" }`; `- debug: msg="{{ [None] | to_json }}"` > `ok: [localhost] => { "msg": "[null]" }`

Comment: I'm not sure how to show it in a comment without losing all of the formatting, so I put it here in a paste: https://pastebin.com/b33hcdyp

Comment: @bmaupin this unrelated to the issue at end, here, you are using a Jinja expression in your value and Jinja always create strings, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70259063/string-does-not-convert-to-integer-in-ansible-playbook

Comment: There is an easy way to resolve this in your case though, make `definition.spec.hard` a local variable and combine the `limits.cpu` in the variable.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/b-enoit-be/4345eac4eb5ee155b1ed0f8638a75c3e

Comment: Could have, or maybe even should have been a question on its own, to be honest.

Comment: I think you're right, this should have been a separate question. My apologies. Thanks for the response.